# The requested URL /laravel-filemanager was not found on this server in UniSharp/laravel-filemanager

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1, file-manager

I am using [UniSharp/laravel-filemanager](https://github.com/UniSharp/laravel-filemanager) and I've done all steps to install it  , but when I want to use it i face this error :

I am using laravel 5.1 on wamp server

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /laravel-filemanager was not found on this server.
>
> Apache/2.4.9 (Win64) PHP/5.5.12 Server at localhost Port 80

this is php artisan route:list

```
    ndex                             | admin
           |
|        | GET|HEAD|POST|PUT|PATCH|DELETE | area/{_missing}
                               |      | App\Http\Controllers\HomeController@miss
ingMethod                        | admin
           |
|        | GET|HEAD                       | check
                               |      | App\Http\Controllers\CheckController@get
Index                            |
           |
|        | GET|HEAD                       | check/index/{one?}/{two?}/{three?}/{
four?}/{five?}                 |      | App\Http\Controllers\CheckController@get
Index                            |
           |
|        | GET|HEAD                       | check/tweet/{one?}/{two?}/{three?}/{
four?}/{five?}                 |      | App\Http\Controllers\CheckController@get
Tweet                            |
           |
|        | GET|HEAD|POST|PUT|PATCH|DELETE | check/{_missing}
                               |      | App\Http\Controllers\CheckController@mis
singMethod                       |
           |
|        | GET|HEAD                       | dashboard
                               |      | App\Http\Controllers\DashboardController
@getIndex                        | admin
           |
|        | GET|HEAD                       | dashboard/index/{one?}/{two?}/{three
?}/{four?}/{five?}             |      | App\Http\Controllers\DashboardController
@getIndex                        | admin
           |
|        | GET|HEAD|POST|PUT|PATCH|DELETE | dashboard/{_missing}
                               |      | App\Http\Controllers\DashboardController
@missingMethod                   | admin
           |
|        | GET|HEAD                       | index/{one?}/{two?}/{three?}/{four?}
/{five?}                       |      | App\Http\Controllers\PublicController@ge
tIndex                           |
           |
|        | GET|HEAD                       | laravel-filemanager
                               |      | Unisharp\Laravelfilemanager\controllers\
LfmController@show               | admin,\Unisharp\Laravelfilemanager\middleware
\MultiUser |
|        | GET|HEAD                       | laravel-filemanager/crop
                               |      | Unisharp\Laravelfilemanager\controllers\
CropController@getCrop           | admin,\Unisharp\Laravelfilemanager\middleware
\MultiUser |
|        | GET|HEAD                       | laravel-filemanager/cropimage
                               |      | Unisharp\Laravelfilemanager\controllers\
CropController@getCropimage      | admin,\Unisharp\Laravelfilemanager\middleware
\MultiUser |
|        | GET|HEAD                       | laravel-filemanager/delete
                               |      | Unisharp\Laravelfilemanager\controllers\
DeleteController@getDelete       | admin,\Unisharp\Laravelfilemanager\middleware
\MultiUser |
|        | GET|HEAD                       | laravel-filemanager/deletefolder
                               |      | Unisharp\Laravelfilemanager\controllers\
FolderController@getDeletefolder | admin,\Unisharp\Laravelfilemanager\middleware
\MultiUser |
|        | GET|HEAD                       | laravel-filemanager/doresize
                               |      | Unisharp\Laravelfilemanager\controllers\
ResizeController@performResize   | admin,\Unisharp\Laravelfilemanager\middleware
\MultiUser |
|        | GET|HEAD                       | laravel-filemanager/download
                               |      | Unisharp\Laravelfilemanager\controllers\
DownloadController@getDownload   | admin,\Unisharp\Laravelfilemanager\middleware
\MultiUser |
|        | GET|HEAD                       | laravel-filemanager/folders
                               |      | Unisharp\Laravelfilemanager\controllers\
FolderController@getFolders      | admin,\Unisharp\Laravelfilemanager\middleware
\MultiUser |
|        | GET|HEAD                       | laravel-filemanager/jsonitems
                               |      | Unisharp\Laravelfilemanager\controllers\
ItemsController@getItems         | admin,\Unisharp\Laravelfilemanager\middleware
\MultiUser |
|        | GET|HEAD                       | laravel-filemanager/newfolder
                               |      | Unisharp\Laravelfilemanager\controllers\
FolderController@getAddfolder    | admin,\Unisharp\Laravelfilemanager\middleware
\MultiUser |
|        | GET|HEAD                       | laravel-filemanager/rename
                               |      | Unisharp\Laravelfilemanager\controllers\
RenameController@getRename       | admin,\Unisharp\Laravelfilemanager\middleware
\MultiUser |
|        | GET|HEAD                       | laravel-filemanager/resize
                               |      | Unisharp\Laravelfilemanager\controllers\
ResizeController@getResize       | admin,\Unisharp\Laravelfilemanager\middleware
\MultiUser |
|        | GET|HEAD|POST|PUT|PATCH|DELETE | laravel-filemanager/upload
                               |      | Unisharp\Laravelfilemanager\controllers\
UploadController@upload          | admin,\Unisharp\Laravelfilemanager\middleware
\MultiUser |
|        | GET|HEAD                       | login
                               |      | App\Http\Controllers\LoginController@get
Index                            |
           |
|        | POST                           | login/check/{one?}/{two?}/{three?}/{
four?}/{five?}                 |      | App\Http\Controllers\LoginController@pos
tCheck                           |
           |
|        | GET|HEAD                       | login/index/{one?}/{two?}/{three?}/{
four?}/{five?}                 |      | App\Http\Controllers\LoginController@get
Index                            |
           |
|        | GET|HEAD                       | login/logout/{one?}/{two?}/{three?}/
{four?}/{five?}                |      | App\Http\Controllers\LoginController@get
Logout                           |
           |
|        | GET|HEAD|POST|PUT|PATCH|DELETE | login/{_missing}
                               |      | App\Http\Controllers\LoginController@mis
singMethod                       |
           |
|        | GET|HEAD                       | n/{one?}/{two?}/{three?}/{four?}/{fi
ve?}                           |      | App\Http\Controllers\PublicController@ge
tN                               |
           |
|        | GET|HEAD                       | post
                               |      | App\Http\Controllers\PostController@getI
ndex                             | admin
           |
|        | GET|HEAD                       | post/index/{one?}/{two?}/{three?}/{f
our?}/{five?}                  |      | App\Http\Controllers\PostController@getI
ndex                             | admin
           |
|        | GET|HEAD|POST|PUT|PATCH|DELETE | post/{_missing}
                               |      | App\Http\Controllers\PostController@miss
ingMethod                        | admin
           |
|        | GET|HEAD                       | profile
                               |      | App\Http\Controllers\ProfileController@g
etIndex                          | admin,administrator
           |
|        | GET|HEAD                       | profile/academic/{one?}/{two?}/{thre
e?}/{four?}/{five?}            |      | App\Http\Controllers\ProfileController@g
etAcademic                       | admin,academic
           |
|        | POST                           | profile/academicstaff/{one?}/{two?}/
{three?}/{four?}/{five?}       |      | App\Http\Controllers\ProfileController@p
ostAcademicstaff                 | admin,academic
           |
|        | POST                           | profile/administrator/{one?}/{two?}/
{three?}/{four?}/{five?}       |      | App\Http\Controllers\ProfileController@p
ostAdministrator                 | admin,administrator
           |
|        | GET|HEAD                       | profile/index/{one?}/{two?}/{three?}
/{four?}/{five?}               |      | App\Http\Controllers\ProfileController@g
etIndex                          | admin,administrator
           |
|        | GET|HEAD                       | profile/standard/{one?}/{two?}/{thre
e?}/{four?}/{five?}            |      | App\Http\Controllers\ProfileController@g
etStandard                       | admin,standard
           |
|        | POST                           | profile/standard/{one?}/{two?}/{thre
e?}/{four?}/{five?}            |      | App\Http\Controllers\ProfileController@p
ostStandard                      | admin,standard
           |
|        | GET|HEAD|POST|PUT|PATCH|DELETE | profile/{_missing}
                               |      | App\Http\Controllers\ProfileController@m
issingMethod                     | admin
           |
|        | GET|HEAD                       | register
                               |      | App\Http\Controllers\RegisterController@
getIndex                         |
           |
|        | GET|HEAD                       | register/academic/{one?}/{two?}/{thr
ee?}/{four?}/{five?}           |      | App\Http\Controllers\RegisterController@
getAcademic                      |
           |
|        | GET|HEAD                       | register/index/{one?}/{two?}/{three?
}/{four?}/{five?}              |      | App\Http\Controllers\RegisterController@
getIndex                         |
           |
|        | POST                           | register/standard/{one?}/{two?}/{thr
ee?}/{four?}/{five?}           |      | App\Http\Controllers\RegisterController@
postStandard                     |
           |
|        | GET|HEAD                       | register/standard/{one?}/{two?}/{thr
ee?}/{four?}/{five?}           |      | App\Http\Controllers\RegisterController@
getStandard                      |
           |
|        | POST                           | register/store/{one?}/{two?}/{three?
}/{four?}/{five?}              |      | App\Http\Controllers\RegisterController@
postStore                        |
           |
|        | POST                           | register/storeacademicstaff/{one?}/{
two?}/{three?}/{four?}/{five?} |      | App\Http\Controllers\RegisterController@
postStoreacademicstaff           |
           |
|        | GET|HEAD|POST|PUT|PATCH|DELETE | register/{_missing}
                               |      | App\Http\Controllers\RegisterController@
missingMethod                    |
           |
|        | GET|HEAD                       | reset
                               |      | App\Http\Controllers\ResetPassController
@getIndex                        | admin
           |
|        | POST                           | reset/delete/{one?}/{two?}/{three?}/
{four?}/{five?}                |      | App\Http\Controllers\ResetPassController
@postDelete                      | admin
           |
|        | GET|HEAD                       | reset/delete/{one?}/{two?}/{three?}/
{four?}/{five?}                |      | App\Http\Controllers\ResetPassController
@getDelete                       | admin
           |
|        | GET|HEAD                       | reset/index/{one?}/{two?}/{three?}/{
four?}/{five?}                 |      | App\Http\Controllers\ResetPassController
@getIndex                        | admin
           |
|        | POST                           | reset/save/{one?}/{two?}/{three?}/{f
our?}/{five?}                  |      | App\Http\Controllers\ResetPassController
@postSave                        | admin
           |
|        | GET|HEAD|POST|PUT|PATCH|DELETE | reset/{_missing}
                               |      | App\Http\Controllers\ResetPassController
@missingMethod                   | admin
           |
|        | GET|HEAD                       | seminar
                               |      | App\Http\Controllers\SeminarController@g
etIndex                          | admin
           |
|        | POST                           | seminar/approve/{one?}/{two?}/{three
?}/{four?}/{five?}             |      | App\Http\Controllers\SeminarController@p
ostApprove                       | admin,administrator
           |
|        | GET|HEAD                       | seminar/approve/{one?}/{two?}/{three
?}/{four?}/{five?}             |      | App\Http\Controllers\SeminarController@g
etApprove                        | admin,administrator
           |
|        | POST                           | seminar/book/{one?}/{two?}/{three?}/
{four?}/{five?}                |      | App\Http\Controllers\SeminarController@p
ostBook                          | admin
           |
|        | GET|HEAD                       | seminar/book/{one?}/{two?}/{three?}/
{four?}/{five?}                |      | App\Http\Controllers\SeminarController@g
etBook                           | admin
           |
|        | POST                           | seminar/cancele/{one?}/{two?}/{three
?}/{four?}/{five?}             |      | App\Http\Controllers\SeminarController@p
ostCancele                       | admin
           |
|        | POST                           | seminar/checktwitter/{one?}/{two?}/{
three?}/{four?}/{five?}        |      | App\Http\Controllers\SeminarController@p
ostChecktwitter                  | admin
           |
|        | POST                           | seminar/create/{one?}/{two?}/{three?
}/{four?}/{five?}              |      | App\Http\Controllers\SeminarController@p
ostCreate                        | admin
           |
|        | POST                           | seminar/crop/{one?}/{two?}/{three?}/
{four?}/{five?}                |      | App\Http\Controllers\SeminarController@p
ostCrop                          | admin
           |
|        | POST                           | seminar/delete/{one?}/{two?}/{three?
}/{four?}/{five?}              |      | App\Http\Controllers\SeminarController@p
ostDelete                        | admin
           |
|        | GET|HEAD                       | seminar/deletefile/{one?}/{two?}/{th
ree?}/{four?}/{five?}          |      | App\Http\Controllers\SeminarController@g
etDeletefile                     | admin
           |
|        | POST                           | seminar/edit/{one?}/{two?}/{three?}/
{four?}/{five?}                |      | App\Http\Controllers\SeminarController@p
ostEdit                          | admin,seminar
           |
|        | GET|HEAD                       | seminar/edit/{one?}/{two?}/{three?}/
{four?}/{five?}                |      | App\Http\Controllers\SeminarController@g
etEdit                           | admin,seminar
           |
|        | GET|HEAD                       | seminar/index/{one?}/{two?}/{three?}
/{four?}/{five?}               |      | App\Http\Controllers\SeminarController@g
etIndex                          | admin
           |
|        | GET|HEAD                       | seminar/new/{one?}/{two?}/{three?}/{
four?}/{five?}                 |      | App\Http\Controllers\SeminarController@g
etNew                            | admin,seminar
           |
|        | GET|HEAD                       | seminar/show/{one?}/{two?}/{three?}/
{four?}/{five?}                |      | App\Http\Controllers\SeminarController@g
etShow                           | admin
           |
|        | POST                           | seminar/upimage/{one?}/{two?}/{three
?}/{four?}/{five?}             |      | App\Http\Controllers\SeminarController@p
ostUpimage                       | admin
           |
|        | GET|HEAD|POST|PUT|PATCH|DELETE | seminar/{_missing}
                               |      | App\Http\Controllers\SeminarController@m
issingMethod                     | admin
           |
|        | GET|HEAD                       | show/{one?}/{two?}/{three?}/{four?}/
{five?}                        |      | App\Http\Controllers\PublicController@ge
tShow                            |
           |
|        | GET|HEAD|POST|PUT|PATCH|DELETE | {_missing}
                               |      | App\Http\Controllers\PublicController@mi
ssingMethod                      |
           |
+--------+--------------------------------+-------------------------------------
-------------------------------+------+-----------------------------------------
---------------------------------+----------------------------------------------
-----------+

C:\wamp\www\socms>
```

Comment: Can you show the output of `php artisan routes`?

Comment: So the route is there, what does your Apache `<VirtualHost>` entry look like for this site?

Comment: @JoshRumbut I Found when I use php artisan serv file manager works good  in local ! but when I want to use my  cms on server online I can not use php artisan serv and I have problem on  none-root  directories !